# Appending Once in Javascript

Tags: javascript, append, html-lists

How would I go about appending the following code once:

```
$('.faq_info').append(
                            '<ul>' +
                            '<li>Highlighted code for double html, body, and head tags means its invalid.</li>' +
                            '<li>Check highlighted iframe tags if it effects link placement.</li>' +
                            '<li>Highlighted charset means its not UTF8 or it is a bad charset.</li>' +
                            '<li>Highlighted symbols means that they are effecting the link.</li>' +
                            '<li>Check highlighted comments if it effects the link placement.</li>' +
                            '<li>If client url is highlighted it means something else in the source is causing it to be invalid.</li>' +
                            '<li>Check to see if client url is in the source code.</li>' +
                            '</ul>'
                        );
```

Comment: You are appending it once... to every element with class `.faq_info`...

Comment: Your selector returns a nodeList, which is then passed to the `append()` method which applies the `append()` to *every* DOM node in that nodeList. To append it only to a specific element, you'll need to use a more specific selector than just a class name.

Comment: @DavidThomas - jQuery doesn't return a NodeList. `.getElementsByClassName()` is supposed to return a _live_ NodeList, but jQuery definitely doesn't, it returns a jQuery object containing (references to) all matching elements. (But of course you are right that the `.append()` then adds to every matching element.)

Comment: Or you could append it only to the first matched element by calling the `eq()` method before `append()`: `$('.faq_info').eq(0).append('...')`. Also, only using a .class selector is way slower than specifying the _type_ of element as well: `div.faq_info` (for example).

Comment: @nnnnnn: I stand corrected! And yeah; I completely forgot about that. And the jQuery object. ...sigh. I should read the API before I try to sound clever in future... =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just did the following $('div.faq_info').empty().append('whatever string'); and it works. It basically empties whatever is in the div and appends after.